# How to get Account Name using Account Id inside AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-http-api

I'm working on an AWS Lambda function using Node.js 12.x. I have the accountId that I pulled from the `event.requestContext`. Is there a way how to get the name of the account using the accountId inside the lambda function?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually list the account aliases using api call [ListAccountAliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccountAliases.html). The corresponding example in from the [documentaiton](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/iam-examples-account-aliases.html)

```
        // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    // Set the region 
    AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

    // Create the IAM service object
    var iam = new AWS.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});

    iam.listAccountAliases({MaxItems: 10}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success", data);
    }
    });
```